# JavaScript make basic polyfill for event.key alert event.keyCode to modernize Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, polyfills

In short, how do I make `alert(event.key)` return the `event.keyCode`?

I just need to know how to make it so `alert(event.key);` becomes `alert(event.keyCode);` because once I'm that far I can remap everything just fine.

The `event.keyCode` method has been deprecated. I've never messed with JavaScript `prototype` and it is my understanding that it's used to essentially create a polyfill for older browsers (like say, Chrome 40 that doesn't support `event.key` because ...?). I'm not looking for the entire function to be coded out, I just want to alert the `keyCode` because from there I can figure out the mapping code and update this question with the working code.

What I've been experimenting with:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event)
{
 if (!event.key)
 {
  Object.defineProperty(String.prototype,'key',
  {
   enumerable: false,
   configurable: false,
   writable: false,
   value: function(event.keyCode)
   {
    alert('event.keyCode = '+event.keyCode);
   }
  });
 }

 alert('event.key = '+event.key);
}
```

No frameworks.

Comment: lol at MDN: "This shouldn't be used by new web applications. IE and Firefox already (partially) support KeyboardEvent.key. Also, Google Chrome and Safari support KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier " yes, don't use the one thing that's worked since day one, use a hodge podge of different stuff, thanks.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(KeyboardEvent.prototype, "key", {get: function(){return this.keyCode;}});` seems to please chrome

Comment: If you use @dandavis 's solution, don't forget to test for the existance of _key_ before applying this change; `if(!('key' in new KeyboardEvent('keydown')) { ... }` -- not sure about IE behaviour, may need to use a `try..catch` around the whole thing, too

Comment: @PaulS: you should check for keyCode too, lest it be removed unexpectedly...

Comment: Working on refining the answer to work with my code so `event.key` will work flawlessly on Chrome, I'll update the question when I'm finished. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining [dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189547/javascript-make-basic-polyfill-for-event-key-alert-event-keycode-to-modernize-ch#comment46593981_29189547) and [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189547/javascript-make-basic-polyfill-for-event-key-alert-event-keycode-to-modernize-ch#comment46594029_29189547) comments, here is a shim with a little error handling

```
(function () {
    var ev;
    try {
        ev = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
        if (!('key' in ev)) {
            if (!('keyCode' in ev))
                if (console && console.warn)
                    console.warn('Someting went wrong setting up keyboardEvent.key; no keyboardEvent.keyCode');
            Object.defineProperty(
                KeyboardEvent.prototype,
                'key',
                {get: function () {return this.keyCode;}}
            );
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (console && console.warn)
            console.warn('Someting went wrong setting up keyboardEvent.key; an error was thrown');
    }
}());
```

Comment: While extremely messy it does what I need, thank you! I'll post the full code once I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Works in Chrome 40 now and I've manually verified each `keyCode`:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event)
{
 if (!event.key)
 {
  Object.defineProperty(KeyboardEvent.prototype,'key',
  {
   get: function ()
   {
    var r;
    var k = {'65':'a','66':'b','67':'c','68':'d','69':'e','70':'f','71':'g','72':'h','73':'i','74':'j','75':'k','76':'l','77':'m','78':'n','79':'o','80':'p','81':'q','82':'r','83':'s','84':'t','85':'u','86':'v','87':'w','88':'x','89':'y','90':'z','8':'Backspace','9':'Tab','13':'Enter','16':'Shift','17':'Control','18':'Alt','20':'CapsLock','27':'Esc','32':' ','33':'PageUp','34':'PageDown','35':'End','36':'Home','37':'Left','38':'Up','39':'Right','40':'Down','45':'Insert','46':'Del','48':'0','49':'1','50':'2','51':'3','52':'4','53':'5','54':'6','55':'7','56':'8','57':'9','91':'OS','92':'OS','93':'Menu','96':'0','97':'1','98':'2','99':'3','100':'4','101':'5','102':'6','103':'7','104':'8','105':'9','106':'*','107':'+','109':'-','110':'.','111':'/','112':'F1','113':'F2','114':'F3','115':'F4','116':'F5','117':'F6','118':'F7','119':'F8','120':'F9','121':'F10','122':'F11','123':'F12','144':'NumLock','145':'ScrollLock','186':':','187':'=','188':',','189':'-','190':'.','191':'/','192':'`','219':'[','220':'\\','221':']','222':'\''}

    if (k[this.keyCode]) {r = k[this.keyCode];}
    else {r = 'Unknown Key';}
    return r;
   }
  });
 }

 alert('event.key = '+event.key);
}
```